# classifying regression observations

Tags: regression

Take the following regression model:

$y_{i,t}=\alpha + \beta x_{i,t} + \gamma c_{i,t} + \epsilon_{i,t}$

$x$ is the independent variable of interest and $c$ is a control variable. $i$ is an individual and $t$ is a year. For instance, we could try to model the gpa $y$ of student $i$ in year $t$ as a function of how much other students study $x$.

$x$ is positively correlated with $y$, so that $\beta > 0$. If I have the data, I can run this regression and estimate $\beta$. However, not all individuals are equally responsive to how much other students study.\

If I wish to classify each observation $(i,t)$ into a student-year that is influenced by peers or not, what is the best course of action?

One way would be to compute $|y_{i,t}-\beta x_{i,t}| = u_{i,t}$ and rank $u_{i,t}$. When $u_{i,t}$ is small, it means that individual $i$'s grades depend on peer study. When $u_{i,t}$ is large, the opposite holds.

The problem is that this is noisy. What are the data-driven alternatives?

I thought of clustering as an alternative. One dimension is $y$ the other is $x$. Is there a cluster in which both. $y$ and $x$ are high and a cluster in which both are low?

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use linear regression for classification, the typical setup is to define $y_i$ for each $i$th object to take on values of -1 or +1, for two-class problems.  For multi-class problems, when there are e.g. 4 classes, you can use multivariate regression with four $y$ variables, for which the dependent coding is $\mathbf{y}_i=\{-1,-1,-1,+1\}$ for a subject in known class 4.  Then regress these dependent values on your data.  Predictive accuracy regarding your subjects with poor predictive accuracy has to be dealt with by use of different independent predictors and their interactions.

One more thing.  Linear regression for classifaciton works best if the classes are "linearly separable."  If the classes are not linearly separable, you will need to use a different classifier.